# How to have three div heights: one percentage based, one to fill and one based on width of image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**Desired Outcome:**

[image]

**Further Details:**

Right now I am setting the Div height based on estimates (ie. 10% for search bar, 60% for middle and 30% for bottom) and set the thumbnail size to fit well on my Samsung Phone. The problem is that on different phones, the width is different and Div3 ends up with large borders. To complicate matters, Div2 can scroll up/down (minor problem) but Div3 can scroll left/right (moderate problem).

All thumbnail images are guaranteed to be 16:9 (I believe) as they are obtained from here https://img.youtube.com/vi/NJ2YyejQjpw/maxresdefault.jpg

I'm having conceptual issues trying to size a div (Div3) based on the height generated when an image is stretched the (more or less) the screen width)

**Question:**
How can I get the three below divs, while allowing for (1) vertical scrolling in Div2 and (2) horizontal scrolling in Div3

**Code:**
[JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/pukster_5G/py8562gu/1/#&togetherjs=EuuTcm29Oa). Try on iPhone X, it looks weird

Important sections:

```
#search_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    border: 0px;
    float: right;
    padding:0px;
    position: relative;
    background-color:red;
}

#search_results {
    width: 100%;
    height: 58%;
    padding:4px;
    float: right;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:green;
}

#playlist_reel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 32%;
    padding:4px;
    clear: both;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Please give some code.

Comment: @AstroBoyR ok give me 15 mins

Answer (score 1):

I went off the diagrams you included and tried to replicate a simple version of it.

- Use flexbox for column layout
- Have `#search_results` take up as much space as possible
- Have `#search_bar`and `#playlist_reel` take up only the space they occupy (totally adjustable)
- Use a `background-image` for `#search_results` so the element is always covered.
- Use a static `img` in `.bottom` so that it takes up actual DOM space

As for scrolling, the requirement feels a little broad at the time I am posting this. Maybe this demo will get you close enough to experiment with scrolling on your own.

**Note:** This demo is more easily viewed in either "full page" mode (here in SO) or in the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngt5j8hp/5/).

```css
html, body { margin: 0; }

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 380px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#search_bar [type=search] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

#search_results {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/400/500');
  background-size: cover;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div id="search_bar">
     <input placeholder="Search" type="search"> 
   </div>
  <div id="search_results"></div>
  <div id="playlist_reel">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/50" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3hbLtv1/1/)